# Flink Avro state evolution

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

I have a flink topology which use a ListState[MyAvroClass] in a CoProcessFunction.

In my CoProcessFunction, I initialize

```js
var myState: ListState[MyAvroClass] = _

override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
  val avroSerializer = new AvroSerializer[MyAvroClass](classOf[MyAvroClass])
  myState = getRuntimeContext.getListState[MyAvroClass](new ListStateDescriptor[MyAvroClass]("myState", avroSerializer))
}
```

It runs ok, but I can't handle avro schema evolutions. Even if I'm restarting my job from a savepoint, I have issues to deserialize the data, for example when I iterate through the listState iterator.

I keep having the error :

```html
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 738197505
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:424)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroSerializer.deserialize(AvroSerializer.java:201)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBListState.deserializeNextElement(RocksDBListState.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBListState.deserializeList(RocksDBListState.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBListState.getInternal(RocksDBListState.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBListState.get(RocksDBListState.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBListState.get(RocksDBListState.java:61)
```

It seems he is trying to fetch a field which is not present in the previous version of my avro class. Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: What version of Flink are you using?

Comment: I am using flink 1.6.0

Comment: Can you try Flink 1.7.1? Support for Avro schema evolution was added in Flink 1.7.

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly to evolve an avro schema when using flink 1.7.1, I don't even have to use an AvroSerializer, the flink default serializer do the job.